# camera not getting opened in cordova 3.5.1

Tags: android, cordova

i am using phonegap cordova 3.5.1 for android using Eclipse.i have used below code to open camera  but its not getting opened.As it is just upgradation same code works fine in cordova 2.9.0 but not in 3.5.1 .I have used required plugins and given permission in config.xml and manifest.xml even then its not working.i am new to android and cordova any help is appreciated

```
function onPhotoFileSuccess(imageData) {
                    $('#idDelImgPhotoImg').append('<div class="mainPhotodiv"><div class="deleteImg"><img id="ImgIdDelete" src="images/delete.png" alt="" onclick="deleteImg(this)" style="width: 100%" /></div> <div class="photodiv" id="idPhotoDiv"><img src="' + imageData + '" alt="" style="width: 100%;height:50%" id="LocPhotoImag" /></div></div>');

                    $('#idAddPhotoImg').show();
                    Locphotos.push(imageData);
                    $('#idAddanotherphotoImg').hide();
                    if ($('#idDelImgPhotoImg').html().trim()) {
                        $('#idAddPhotoImg').hide();
                        $('#idAddanotherphotoImg').show();


                    }

                    else {

                        $('#idAddanotherphotoImg').hide();
                        $('#idAddPhotoImg').show();
                    }

                }


    function capturePhotoWithFile() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoFileSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });

    };

    function onFail(message) {

    }
function deleteImg(ImgTag) {

        $(ImgTag).parents('.mainPhotodiv').remove();
    }
```

.html

```
<img src="images/Addphoto.png" style="width: 100%" alt="" onclick="capturePhotoWithFile();"/>
    </div>
    <div id="idDelImgPhotoImg">
        <!--<div class="deleteImg">
            <img src="images/delete.png" alt="" style="width: 100%" /></div>
        <div class="photodiv">
            <img src="images/5mount-img.png" alt="" style="width: 100%" /></div>-->
    </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px;display:none;" id="idAddanotherphotoImg"> <img src="images/6Addanotherphoto.png" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="capturePhotoWithFile()"/></div>

       <div id="idVedioShowdiv" style="display:none"></div>
       <div style="margin-top:20px!important;"></div>
```

congif.xml

```
 <rim:permissions>
  <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
 </rim:permissions>

 <access subdomains="true" origin="*"  />
 <access origin="http://2.8.2.3:34/Service.asmx" subdomains="true" />
 <access origin="http://8.9.60.6:9/rt.asmx" subdomains="true" />
 <access origin="http://comp.cloud.net:2/rr" subdomains="true" />
 <access origin="http://comp.cloud.net:91/rr" subdomains="true" />
 <access origin="http://comp.cloud.net:93/rr"  subdomains="true" />

 <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.1" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" version="0.2.11"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="3.3.0" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" version="0.3.3" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" version="0.2.11" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" version="0.2.13" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" version="0.2.10" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" version="0.3.9" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"  version="1.3.1" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"  version="0.4.6" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.10" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" version="0.3.1" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" version="0.2.13" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.12" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" version="0.3.11"  />
```

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: @Nehil Mistry it shows no error,on giving alert it enters function

Comment: Have you checked camera plugin is there in plugin list? `cordova plugin ls`

Comment: @Nehil Mistry inside www folder i have a plugin folder which contains org.apache.cordova.camera containing Camera.js,cameraConstants.js,CameraPopoverhandle.js and CamerapopoverOptions.js

Comment: Please share your config.xml

Comment: @Nehil Mistry config.xml has been shared

Comment: are you using phonegap build service or are you developing locally?

Comment: i am developing locally using plugins and downloading cordova 3.5.1.jar and .js files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by again downloading correct plugins required and adding android:targetSdkVersion="19" in manifest.xml ,which i had left adding.Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20,correctOrientation : true,targetWidth: 700,
  targetHeight: 700,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
 }); 

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        image = imageData;

    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

Comment: config.xml has been shared

Comment: try with removing version numbering in config.xml for camera pluging and follow the sequence of functions for capturing image in the way I edited code in answer..Also try removing media plugin

Comment: not working after removing versions in config.xml file